# Pan gesture interferes with scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer

I have three view controllers that are part of a UIScrollView. I want to be able to swipe between the three, although one of the view controllers has a UIPanGestureRecognizer. I use this pan gesture recognizer to allow the user to drag their finger up and down to increase and decrease the height of a rectangular UIView. Therefore, this UIPanGestureRecognizer only really needs to know about the upwards/downwards panning, and the scroll view can use the horizontal panning.

An example of this, is like the home screen; you can swipe left or right, but also swipe down to get spotlight. I want this kind of mechanism.

This is my code for the pan:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)aPan; // When pan guesture is recognised
{
CGPoint location = [aPan locationInView:self.view]; // Location of finger on screen
CGRect secondRect = CGRectMake(210.0, 45.0, 70.0, 325.0); // Rectangles of maximimum bar area
CGRect minuteRect = CGRectMake(125.0, 45.0, 70.0, 325.0);
CGRect hourRect = CGRectMake(41.0, 45.0, 70.0, 325.0);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(secondRect, location)) { // If finger is inside the 'second' rectangle

    CGPoint currentPoint = [aPan locationInView:self.view];

    currentPoint.y -= 80;  // Make sure animation doesn't go outside the bars' rectangle

    if (currentPoint.y < 0) {
    currentPoint.y = 0;
    }
    else if (currentPoint.y > 239) {
    currentPoint.y = 239;
    }

    currentPoint.y = 239.0 - currentPoint.y;

    CGFloat pointy = currentPoint.y - fmod(currentPoint.y, 4.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01f  // Animate the bars to rise as the finger moves up and down
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect oldFrame = secondBar.frame;
                         secondBar.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, (oldFrame.origin.y - (pointy - secondBar.frame.size.height)), oldFrame.size.width, (pointy));
                     }];

    CGFloat result = secondBar.frame.size.height - fmod(secondBar.frame.size.height, 4.0);

    secondInt = (result / 4.0); // Update labels with new time

    self->secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", secondInt];
}
```

The code is basically repeated for three separate rectangular UIViews.

If anyone can tell me how to get the homescreen-style panning/swiping into my app, that would be great!!

Comment: Can you please share a link to your project (github/dropbox) so I can take a look at it? It's really hard to tell what these bars and labels are.

Comment: Here's the link to the entire project in DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9jqry6y2kr5kltr/VklDgKvoYe Hope this helps! Also, I'm having trouble getting all three view controllers into the scroll view and I'm not sure if the code is right in ScrollViewController.m so if you could help me out with that as well that would be great!

Comment: I wasn't able to open the project. There seems to be a problem with the `Bars.xcodeproj` file. XCode wasn't able to open it and when I opened it with TextEdit it was empty.

Comment: Hmm, does this one work? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9jqry6y2kr5kltr/VklDgKvoYe

Comment: Yes, that one's working. Nice app. Let me see what the problem is and I'll get back to you

Comment: Thank you for going to all this effort! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Alright, here is the short answer:**

You have to use `UIGestureRecognizer`'s method `-requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`.

**And here is the long answer:**

You have to make the pan gesture recognizer of your scroll view to succeed **only** if the pan gesture recognizer of `TimerViewController` fails. However that gesture (`TimerViewController`'s gesture) should **only** succeed if the **initial** movement is vertical. If it is horizontal it should fail.
To accomplish this we have to subclass `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and modify it to fit those needs.
Here is what you have to do:

1. Disregard ALL the changes you made from my previous answer
2. Add `VerticalPanGestureRecognizer` to your project.
3. Modify `TimerViewController` as shown.
4. Modify `ScrollViewController` as shown.

**VerticalPanGestureRecognizer.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface VerticalPanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer

@end
```

**VerticalPanGestureRecognizer.m**

```
#import "VerticalPanGestureRecognizer.h"

@interface VerticalPanGestureRecognizer ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint origLoc;

@end

@implementation VerticalPanGestureRecognizer

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.origLoc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view.superview];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
        CGPoint loc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view.superview];
        CGFloat deltaX = fabs(loc.x - self.origLoc.x);
        CGFloat deltaY = fabs(loc.y - self.origLoc.y);
        if (deltaY < deltaX)
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    }

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

**TimerViewController.h**

```
// Your imports here

@interface TimerViewController : UIViewController

{
    // Your ivars here
}

// Add the following property
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;

// Your methods here

@end
```

**TimerViewController.m**

```
#import "TimerViewController.h"
#import "VerticalPanGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation TimerViewController
@synthesize pan = _pan;

// prefersStatusBarHidden method here

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil // Initialise view controller
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Instantiate the pan gesture as "VerticalPanGestureRecognizer"
        self.pan = [[VerticalPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)]; // Create recogniser for a pan guesture
        self.pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = self.pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
    }

    return self;
}

// The rest of your code here

@end
```

**ScrollViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Your code here

    TimerViewController *tvc = [[TimerViewController alloc]init];
    CGRect frame = tvc.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    tvc.view.frame = frame;

    // Add the following line 
    [self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tvc.pan];

    [self addChildViewController:tvc];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:tvc.view];
    [tvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // More code here
}
```

This new approach works perfectly. I tested it. 
Let me know if you have more questions.

Cheers!

**UPDATE**

To answer the question you posted on the comments, here is what you have to do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    BarsViewController *bvc = [[BarsViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:bvc];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:bvc.view];
    [bvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    TimerViewController *tvc = [[TimerViewController alloc]init];
    CGRect frame = tvc.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    tvc.view.frame = frame;

    [self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tvc.pan];
    [self addChildViewController:tvc];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:tvc.view];
    [tvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    StopwatchViewController *svc = [[StopwatchViewController alloc] init];
    frame = svc.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 320*2;
    svc.view.frame = frame;

    [self addChildViewController:svc];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:svc.view];
    [svc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*3, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
}
```

Again, I tested it and it's working. You just have to add the gesture recognizer for the bars

Comment: This works pretty well thanks! However, the Pan gesture seems less resonsive. For instance, the bar will only change height once you let go of the screen, whereas before, it moved as your finger moved. Also, if I'm moving the bars, the scroll view moves as well. Is it possible to have it so that the scroll view will only move if the finger is moving more in the x direction than in the y, and as for the bars, visa versa? I think this might give the homescreen-style effect I was looking for. Other than that, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user2397282 please see my updated answer. The new approach works perfectly. Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Wow!! This is exactly as I wanted it!! I don't want to seem rude, but if I could just ask for one minor little bit of help? In scrollViewController.m, how do I add my third view controller, StopwatchViewController?? You have been fantastic!! Thank you ever so much!!

Comment: @user2397282 I made another update to my answer to reply to your question. Perhaps you should migrate your project to GitHub and that was I could contribute to your app.

Comment: Thank you!! Okay, I will look into putting on Github tomorrow; I'm just about to go to sleep! I can't believe how helpful you've been today, thank you!!!

Comment: Great Answer, thank you for making it clear.  You saved me a large headache - I have been trying to replicate the functionality you see in Facebook's "Paper" app when pulling up an article (which is a `UIScrollView`), allowing it to be scrolled while its in full screen mode, and only allowing it to be pulled down as a unit via a pan gesture if the scrollview's content offset is at 0 and the pan gesture's movement is downward. Thank you.