# How to intercept vertical swipe gestures

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Is there a way to insert my uitableview into the responder chain so I can process some vertical swipes (based on horizontal position) and pass others on to the underlying uiscrollview?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making my own Gesture Recognizer as explained in this post: [Pan gesture interferes with scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985654/pan-gesture-interferes-with-scroll?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer on the view, configure the direction to be up and down(vertical)

Comment: The tableView seems to consume any vertical swipes before they are passed on to my gesture recognizer.  How can I get the swipe gesture before the table view handles it?